# How to store user responses on-the-fly temporarily for later use?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am looking for the best way to store information that is entered within an Oracle ApEx app that is sectioned off like a wizard.

Basically there are a number of fields on the screen, i.e. text box, text area, select list, checkboxes as well as radiogroup buttons but are not attached to any particular database tables.

What I would like to do is basically have the user enter required answers say on one pane, which might have 5 items in total, i.e., 2 textfields, 1 radiogroup, 1 selectlist and 1 checkbox and when they press the "Next>" button before going to the next pane, store these answers into a ApEx Collection against a particular Id and perform the same process on the following pane of answers entered.

I am using Oracle ApEx 4.1.2. Basically want to store away values on the fly and reuse at a later stage.

Comment: I think using regular items works that way. From page 10, you can use an item created in page 5, no problems with that.

Comment: What @Plouf said. As soon as you submit a page (and usually, the next button will do this), the values of items are submitted to the session state. So as long as the cache of a page is not cleared (or an individual item) then the value of said item will be accessible through the usual notation. Using a collection could also be an option of course, and are bound to a session just like a page item's value.

Comment: Thanks. @Tom - what I am planning on doing is using jQuery, scanning the answer items only and passing these values into a collection. Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: I think you may be trying to do something unnecessary. If you're using items defined in apex, there is no need to scan over these with jQuery. For example, if you have a radiogroup item on page 5 called `P5_MARRIED` with values `YES`and `NO`, then on page submit the item value will be `YES` or `NO` in the session state. ie, `:P5_MARRIED` will provide said value. At the end of your wizard it would only be up to you to collect what values you deem required. If page 5 has other items you are free to ignore those. Their value would only persist in the session after all, not in a table.

Comment: Thanks to both Plouf and Tom. As Tom has suggested, Plouf is was spot on. I basically had this idea that I had to use an ApEx Collection , which after reading these comments, this wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my last comment above, Plouf came through with the goods. I didn't require an ApEx Collection after all - regular items did the trick.