# Issues with On Demand Process Response

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using Oracle ApEx v4.1 together with Dynamic Actions, which basically calls a javascript function, which in turn calls an On Demand Process to save data, to the database.

Just a bit of background, I am using jQuery to scan each of the elements with their values, when the user either presses the "Save" button or the "Next" button, which in turn then passes these elements with values into the above on demand process.

My question/issue is, it looks like sometimes the process is missing the data passed in and I am not sure why and I thought that perhaps in my dynamic action I am performing both a ape.submit('SUBMIT') as well as a JavaScript function call to an on demand process.

Do I need to delay one of these calls, as at the moment, I am unsure why it works sometimes and other times, it doesn't.

Any ideas on how to lay out the code, i.e.

```
apex.submit('SUBMIT');
saveTheData();    <-- calls my ondemand process to save data to database
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's hark back a bit to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269246/how-to-store-user-responses-on-the-fly-temporarily-for-later-use). And what exactly you are exactly doing here. It seems wildly unnecessary!

What reason is there to collect item values in jQuery and submit them to session state when you are submitting the page anyway? When you use a next/prev/appy button and the page submits then the items' values are in session state, and you can use them in processes.

You are submitting the page with apex.submit. This submits the page, and sets all item's values in session state. You perform your JavaScript function which would call an on-demand process, providing values to the process. These values are page item values, and thus you're actually just setting session states in your on-demand process. It honestly seems like you have a real wacky design going on!

As to why it sometimes works, and sometimes it doesn't: `apex.submit` will submit the page. Like, right away. If you need code executed before the page is processed then do it before the submit. Note that if you were to switch the lines around it might still not work, depending on how you call the ondemand process (async or synchronous), and whether you want a success function to do something or not. When the call is async, then it might be your success function is not handled before the submit is done.